# Visual studio where do I get it for community \ express edition for much older versions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express

In order to follow along some old but gold video tutorials, I want to install 2010, because that's what the presenter is using, and it will allow me to ensure that I can follow along exactly without much surprises.

But, where do I get older versions?

I visited the link below, but it doesn't say community or express:
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/

(I think, back then, they used to call the free version "express")

Comment: It's right there on that page, just scroll down and expand the 2010 grouping and you'll see the express version on the list.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I wasn't lookin' there.